# Why do my custom CSS styles get removed when trying to bring this JavaScript file, into my Vaadin application?

Tags: javascript, java, css, vaadin, lit

---

```js
import {css, html, LitElement} from 'lit';

class AnalogClock extends LitElement {

    static get properties() {
        return {
            time: {type: Date},
            interval: {type: Object}
        };
    }

    static get styles() {
        return css`
       
    .clock {
  width: 30rem;
  height: 30rem;
  border: 7px solid #282828;
  box-shadow: -4px -4px 10px rgba(67,67,67,0.5),
                inset 4px 4px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
                inset -4px -4px 10px rgba(67,67,67,0.5),
                4px 4px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2rem;
 
}

.outer-clock-face {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #282828;
  
 
  overflow: hidden;
}

.outer-clock-face::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg)
}

.outer-clock-face::before,
.outer-clock-face::after,
.outer-clock-face .marking{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1df52f;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 49%;
}

.outer-clock-face .marking {
  background: #bdbdcb;
  width: 3px;
}

.outer-clock-face .marking.marking-one {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg)
}

.outer-clock-face .marking.marking-two {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
  transform: rotate(60deg)
}

.outer-clock-face .marking.marking-three {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
  transform: rotate(120deg)
}

.outer-clock-face .marking.marking-four {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(150deg);
  transform: rotate(150deg)
}

.inner-clock-face {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  background: #282828;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.inner-clock-face::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 18px;
  margin-left: -9px;
  margin-top: -6px;
  background: #4d4b63;
  z-index: 11;
}

.hand {
  width: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  height: 6px;
  background: #61afff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  border-radius: 6px;
  transform-origin: 100%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 2.7, 0.58, 1);
}

.hand.hour-hand {
  width: 30%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.hand.min-hand {
  height: 3px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 40%;
}

.hand.second-hand {
  background: #ee791a;
  width: 45%;
  height: 2px;
}

        `;
    }

    render() {
        return html`
            <div class="clock">
                <div class="outer-clock-face">
                    <div class="marking marking-one"></div>
                    <div class="marking marking-two"></div>
                    <div class="marking marking-three"></div>
                    <div class="marking marking-four"></div>
                    <div class="inner-clock-face">
                        <div class="hand hour-hand"></div>
                        <div class="hand min-hand"></div>
                        <div class="hand second-hand"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        `;
    }

    setDate(time) {

        const secondHand = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.second-hand');
        const minsHand = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.min-hand');
        const hourHand = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.hour-hand');

        const now = time;

        const seconds = now.getSeconds();
        const secondsDegrees = ((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90;
        secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsDegrees}deg)`;

        const mins = now.getMinutes();
        const minsDegrees = ((mins / 60) * 360) + ((seconds / 60) * 6) + 90;
        minsHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minsDegrees}deg)`;

        const hour = now.getHours();
        const hourDegrees = ((hour / 12) * 360) + ((mins / 60) * 30) + 90;
        hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${hourDegrees}deg)`;
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.time = new Date();

        this.updateComplete.then(() => {
                this.setDate(this.time);

                this.interval = setInterval(() => {
                    this.time = new Date(this.time.setSeconds(this.time.getSeconds() + 1));
                    this.setDate(this.time);
                }, 1000);
            }
        );
    }
}

window.customElements.define('analog-clock', AnalogClock);
```

---

[My component class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os17D.png)

[The view where I bring the clock in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOdJc.png)

[The result of bringing the clock into the application, which has removed all my previous styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZUXz.png)

The clock is a JavaScript file which I have very little experience using, I am bringing the clock into my Vaadin application using the spring @JsModule annotation and it appears to be over riding all my current CSS styling. If anyone can shed some light on this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking
a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What do you mean by "it appears to be over riding all my current CSS styling"? What other styles do you have in the application, what are they styling/targeting?

Comment: Any errors in the browser's JS console?